# Negative index runtime error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am using [this](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/bicubic-interpolation-image-processing/source/browse/trunk/libimage.c) as my reference to implement my version of Bicubic interpolation for resizing the images. Here is the function that I have so far with some changes.

```
    IplImage * bicubic(IplImage *img, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    IplImage *img2 ;
    img2 = createImage(newWidth,newHeight);
    uchar * data = (uchar*)img->imageData;
    uchar * Data = (uchar*)img2->imageData;
    //int a,b,c,index;

    uchar Cc;
    uchar C[5];
    uchar d0,d2,d3,a0,a1,a2,a3;
    int i,j,k,jj;
    int x,y;
    float dx,dy;
    float tx,ty;

    tx =  (float)img->width /newWidth ;
    ty =  (float)img->height / newHeight;
    printf("New Width = %d, New Height = %d WidthStep = %d", newWidth, newHeight,img->widthStep);

    for(i = 0; i< newHeight; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j< newWidth; j++)
        {       
            x = (int)(tx * j);
            y = (int)(ty * i);

            dx = tx * j - x;
            dy = ty * i - y;

            for(k = 0;k < 3;k++)
            {
                for(jj = 0;jj <= 3 ;jj++)
                {                                       
                    int z = (y - 1 + jj);
                    //if(z > -1){
                    a0 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x)*img->nChannels +k];//===>Throws of runtime error
                    d0 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x-1)*img->nChannels +k] - a0 ;
                    d2 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x+1)*img->nChannels +k] - a0 ;
                    d3 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x+2)*img->nChannels +k] - a0 ;

                    a1 = -1.0/3 * d0 + d2 -1.0/6*d3;
                    a2 =  1.0/2 * d0 + 1.0/2*d2;
                    a3 = -1.0/6 * d0 - 1.0/2*d2 + 1.0/6*d3;
                    C[jj] = a0 + a1*dx + a2*dx*dx + a3*dx*dx*dx;

                    d0 = C[0]-C[1];
                    d2 = C[2]-C[1];
                    d3 = C[3]-C[1];
                    a0 = C[1];
                    a1 = -1.0/3*d0 + d2 -1.0/6*d3;
                    a2 =  1.0/2*d0 + 1.0/2*d2;
                    a3 = -1.0/6*d0 - 1.0/2*d2 + 1.0/6*d3;
                    Cc = a0 + a1*dy + a2*dy*dy + a3*dy*dy*dy;

                    Data[i*img2->widthStep +j*img2->nChannels +k ] = Cc;
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return img2;  
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I call this `bicubic` function, it throws off an invalid access runtime error at the line where I find out the value of `a0`. I am using VS 2012 debugger and it tells me that the value of `z` is calculated as `-1`. This causes the index to access the invalid part of memory of `data` array.

My question is, why is this happening? Am I missing something in OpenCV's image library that can help in getting right indices so that I dont run into this error? Or am I making some mistake in accessing the correct indices?

Comment: At very beginning: i == j == jj == 0. Then y == 0. Then z == (0 - 1 + 0) == -1.

Comment: it is 2014 now. stop using the deprecated c-api.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i< newHeight; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j< newWidth; j++)
        {       
            x = (int)(tx * j);
            y = (int)(ty * i);

            dx = tx * j - x;
            dy = ty * i - y;

            for(k = 0;k < 3;k++)
            {
                for(jj = 0;jj <= 3 ;jj++)
                {                                       
                    int z = (y - 1 + jj);

                    //if(z > -1){
                    a0 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x)*img->nChannels +k];//===>Throws of runtime error
                    d0 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x-1)*img->nChannels +k] - a0 ;
```

On the first iteration, `i` and `j` are 0. as are `k` and `jj`

This means that:

```
 y = (int)(ty * i);    //y = ty * 0    (== 0)
int z = (y - 1 + jj);  //z = 0 - 1 + 0 (==-1)
```

And so in the line:

```
a0 = data[z * img->widthStep + (x)*img->nChannels +k];//===>Throws of runtime error
```

the index is:

```
(-1) * img->widthStep + (x)*img->nChannels +k
```

simplifies to:

```
(-1) * img->widthStep + 0 + 0
```

which is:

```
-img->widthStep
```

This is of course out of bounds, leading to the crash.

Comment: Looking at your link, I don't see how it doesn't suffer from the same. Also in that code there are odd things there too, e.g. `index,a,b,c` are initialised and not used, `d` doesn't even get that far.